# c++ windows ip release and renew

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I took code from here:

[IpRenewAddress function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366057(v=vs.85).aspx)

Created a new empty Win32 project and put the code in it.

Built and ran.

All is OK. There isn't any error.

But...

Result of:

```
dwRetVal = IpReleaseAddress(&pInfo->Adapter[0])
```

and

```
dwRetVal = IpRenewAddress(&pInfo->Adapter[0])
```

dwRetVal=2, which describing is "the system cannot find the file specified".

I turned off all optimizations, turn on all notifications.

Properties:

> /INCREMENTAL:NO

Linker output file is

> $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)

I've watched "C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.setup", where there is record

> "Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
>   DeleteFile:'C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\nvgfx.sys' 
> ..."

Deleted nvidia drivers,reboot- didn't help.

I have only one warning in "corect.h" in "Windows API Partitioning and ARM Desktop Support" block when include "windows.h"

> error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

It is only with /WX flag.

Can anybody help?

New:

Checked all interfaces. "Cannot find..." for all.

### New 2

ipconfig /all show that dchp is disabled
if i turn it in settings all's working.
But if I change ip with wmi,dhcp turn off again.

Does anybody know how activate dhcp using c++?

### New 3

DHCP service didn't stop after changing ip address.
Service is working,but

> Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . . :
>   Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
>   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-D3-C1-3F-83-C4
>   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
>   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.12.23
>   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.12.1
>   DNS Servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
>   8.8.4.4
>   NetBios over Tcp/Ip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Restart DHCP servise doesn't help.
How turn dhcp on not via service?

Comment: You may have multiple network adapters on your system, some of them might not be connected. Sample code calls `IpReleaseAddress()` for first adapter only. Have you checked that this is the right adapter?

Comment: Have you actually enabled DHCP for the network adapters? You can see this if you enter `ipconfig /all` in console.

Comment: "Deleted nvidia drivers" - _seriously_ ? Just because you saw the number 2 appear in conjunction with an NVidia file?! We call that the **Strong law of small numbers** - there simply aren't enough small numbers to have a unique meaning for each small number.